# Morphisms between $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: finite-groups, divisibility, cyclic-groups

I'm trying to determinate how many morphisms of groupes exist between $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ for $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$.

I know a morphism is determinated by the image of the class $1$ and all image $g$ of $1$ have to satisfy $gn=0$.

My question is, how many elements $g$ like that exist and why?

Comment: What do you mean by "all the image $g$ of 1"? Do you mean, "if 1 maps to an element $g$ then $g$ must satisfy $gn=0$"? Also, it would be good if you could mention anything you have tried so far

Comment: I found that the subgroup of solution is generated by $\dfrac{m}{gcd(n,m)}$ Anybody know why?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint* Let $1\in \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ be your generator, $\eta$ a morphism. Then the order of $\eta(1)\in \Bbb Z/m \Bbb Z$ divides the order $n$ of $1$ in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ and $m$, so ${\rm ord}\,\eta(1)\mid (n,m)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ nk\equiv 0\pmod m\!\iff\! m\mid nk\!\iff\! m\mid (nk,mk)=(n,m)k\!\iff\! m/(n,m)\mid k$